# Make an edge fit its label size in Tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I am using the Tikz graph library to draw a suffix tree, and I would like the edges' sizes to fit their labels. Is that possible?. Some labels are short and other long, so the tree is of variable length. The only function I know is level distance, but it sets the same distance to all the nodes in a same tree level.

This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usegdlibrary {trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\graph[edge quotes={fill=white,inner sep=0pt, font=\tiny\ttfamily},
       tree layout,
       sibling distance=0pt,
       level distance=0pt,
       nodes={circle,draw}]{

    "" -> {""[>"\$"],
           ""[>"a"] --[sloped] {""[>"gg", level distance=2.3cm] --[sloped] {""[>"\$tcgggattc"],
                                                                            ""[>"gct\$"]},
                                ""[>"tt"] --[sloped] {""[>"aaaa"],
                                                      ""[>"cggattaggcttagggct\$"]}
                                },
           ""[>"c", level distance=2.2cm] --[sloped] { ""[>"\$tcgggattcggattagg"],
                                                       ""[>"t"] },
           ""[>"g"],
           ""[>"t"]}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the image I obtain:

[image]

I would like the edges labeled with gg and tt to fit the labels.

Any help would be appreciated :)